# How to set font family and page break in google doc php API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-api-php-client, google-docs-api

I want to add default font family 'Calbri' to my google doc which is generated by PHP API.
I have search more and more but not find any specific solution for my problem.

```
$parent = 'XXXXX';
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
        array(
            'name' => 'XXXX',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',    
            'teamDriveId' => $parent,
            'parents' => array($parent)
        )
    );
    $filename = 'XXXX';
    $file->setName($filename);
    $file->setMimeType( 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' );

    $result = $this->serviceDrive->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => file_get_contents("path/to/file"),
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    ));
```

How can I add default font, page break and table of content on my google doc?

Comment: Don't think this is doable at this point. However, try checking Apps Script's [setFontFamily](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setFontFamily(String)) if it can serve as an alternative.

Comment: Would be interested to find it out as well. Did you find any solutions?